# vite build assets not loading for laravel vite application

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-10

vite build assets not loading for laravel vite application on live nginx server. I am trying to host laravel vite application on subdirectory(https://laravel.domain.com/modernapp).but getting for 404 error on page loading. and its not loading assets. getting the following error.

`https://laravel.domain.com/build/assets/main-911fc821.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` .

but according to me it should load assets on following url.

`https://laravel.domain.com/modernapp/build/assets/main-911fc821.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

My vite.config.js file

```
`import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
 import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
 import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
 import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
 import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
 import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
 import { defineConfig } from 'vite'


  export default defineConfig({
   plugins: [
  laravel({
  input: ['resources/js/main.js'],
  refresh: true,
  }),
  vue({
  template: {
  transformAssetUrls: {
      base: null,
      includeAbsolute: false,
  },
 },
 }),
vueJsx(),

// https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify- 
loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin

Components({
  dirs: ['resources/js/components'],
  dts: true,
}),
AutoImport({
  eslintrc: {
    enabled: true,
    filepath: './.eslintrc-auto-import.json',
  },
  imports: ['vue', 'vue-router', '@vueuse/core', '@vueuse/math', 
'pinia'],
  vueTemplate: true,
}),
 ],
 define: { 'process.env': {} },
 resolve: {
alias: {
  '@core-scss': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/styles/@core', 
 import.meta.url)),
  '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js', import.meta.url))
},
},
 build: {
chunkSizeWarningLimit: 5000,
 },
 // optimizeDeps: {
 //   exclude: ['vuetify','maska'],
 //   // entries: [
 //   //   './resources/js/**/*.vue',
//   // ],
// },
 })
```

Comment: the problem should be in your nginx config, you put your application in a sub-page, `/modernapp` but your nginx config treat it like its on the root directory '/` and its not adding that subpage on the base url

Comment: also, make sure you configure `APP_URL` in your .`env` and should have that `modernapp` subpage